# Swiping in view controller with navigation bar hidden

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

VC(View controller) A push VC B, both with :

`self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true`.

I want to swipe from B to A, like a normal situation when navigation bar is not hidden

Comment: Does `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewControllerB, animated: true)` and `self.navigationController?.popViewController(viewControllerB, animated: true)` work?

Comment: I want that from "B", the only way to get back would be using the swipe gesture

Comment: I'm pushing B with `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewControllerB, animated: true)`

Comment: Look at the [docs for UINavigationController](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/), specifically `popViewController(...)` and `popToViewController(...)`.